# if condition not evaluated - none of the options matches

Tags: javascript

I have a json array that contains an element that can be "ok" or "ko".

If I do `console.log(data.esito)` I see that the value is "ok" or "ko" as expected.

So I tried to do:

```
console.log(data.esito);
if(data.esito == 'ok'){
    console.log('code for ok');
    //code if is ok                
}else{
    console.log('code for ko');
    //code if is ko
}
```

But it never enter the if. Even if the result is "ko" or if the data.esito == 'ok' was faulty the code for ko is not executed.

What am I missing? Must be something obvious but cannot see what

Comment: `if(data.esito.trim() == 'ok')`

Comment: Thanks! can you explain me why it is needed? I don't see a logic reason for that @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the value of your variable `data.esito` has leading or trailing spaces the strict checking of the string `ok` will evaluate false.

You could try using `trim()` to remove any extra whitespace from the beginning or end of the variable.

Comment: thanks! I checked for white spaces around the value and didn't find any in my code. Anyway this way it works!